# Cleaner way of getting x and y axis value from vue-chartjs

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I am currently using vue-chartjs to render a line chart, and I would like to grab the data of the datapoint that I clicked on the line chart. This is currently my code:

```
ClickHandler: function(event) {
    // Here is how to access the chart
    const c = this._data._chart;
    const datapoint = c.getElementAtEvent(event)[0];

    if (datapoint != null) {
        const indexBar = datapoint._index;
        const indexSegment = datapoint._datasetIndex;
        console.log("y axis: " + c["chart"]["data"]["labels"][indexBar]);
        console.log("x axis: " + c["chart"]["data"]["datasets"][indexSegment]);
    }
},
```

Just want to clarify if there are other/cleaner ways to capture the x and y-axis value of the datapoint?

Update:
I did the rendering of my chart like this

```
this.renderChart(this.dataset, this.options);
```

And here is my options code:

```
options: {
        onClick: this.ClickHandler,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        scales: { yAxes: [{ ticks: { beginAtZero: true }, gridLines: { display: true } }], xAxes: [{ gridLines: { display: false } }] },
        legend: {
            display: true,
        },
    },
```

Comment: Can you show the code for your construction of this? The first argument to the datapoint click callback is the `pointer` event, and the 2nd argument is the event which has `x` and `y` which should be accessible through `event[0].model.x` [here's a jsfiddle, if it's helpful](https://jsfiddle.net/qgv8y0oz/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy updated my question, hope it helps to clarify more!